# Conway Maxwell Distribution Density Plot

Tags: r, simulation

I have written my own code to simulate the Conway maxwell distribution sample. 
This is the pmf (Guikema & Goffelt, 2008):
[image]
However, I have met some problem to plot the density plot.

```
rcomp <- function(n,lamb,v)
{
  u <- runif(n)
  w <- integer(n)

  for(i in 1:n) {
    z=sum(sapply(  0:100, function(j) (( ((lamb)^j) / (factorial(j)) )^v)  ))
    x <- seq(1, 50, 1) #seq of 1 to 50, increase by 1
    px <- (((lamb^x)/factorial(x))^v)/z 
    # px is pmf of re-parameter conway maxwell 
    w[i] <- if (u[i] < px[1]) 0 else (max (which (cumsum(px) <= u[i])))
  }
  return (w)
}
dcomp <- function(x,lamb,v) {
z=sum(sapply(  0:100, function(j) (( ((lamb)^j) / (factorial(j)) )^v)  ))
px <- (((lamb^x)/factorial(x))^v)/z

return(px)
}
```

As I wanna plot the density plot to check whether lamb or v is location parameter, the plot I get is weird.

```
x = rcomp(100,6,0.2);  pdf = dcomp(x,6,0.2)
x1 = rcomp(100,6,0.5);  pdf1 = dcomp(x1,6,0.5)
x2 = rcomp(100,6,0.7);  pdf2 = dcomp(x2,6,0.7)
plot(x2, pdf2, type="l", lwd=1,lty=1,col="blue")
```

[image]

How could I solve this problem?

Source: Guikema & Goffelt (2008), A Flexible Count Data Regression Model for Risk Analysis. Risk Analysis 28(1): 215.

Comment: Sort `x2` before computing the pdf: `x2 <- rcomp(100, 6, 0.7);  x2 <- sort(x2); pdf2 <- dcomp(x2, 6, 0.7)`. Also, in the example code above, why compute `x` and `x1` and their respective pdf values? (Nothing wrong with it, just not [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).)

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, actually, i wanna plot 3 curves (x, x1 and x2) in one graph. I will try to sort it first.

Comment: Then use `plot` for the first and `lines` for the others, like I have done in my answer to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to sort the values of the x coordinate if you want a graph to connect the points in their axis order.
Note, however, that there might be better ways to graph the density you want. See the red curve. I first create a vector `x` of values within a certain range and then compute the PDF for those values. These pairs `(x, y)` are what function `lines` plots.

```
set.seed(2673)    # Make the results reproducible

x2 <- rcomp(100, 6, 0.7)
x2 <- sort(x2)
pdf2 <- dcomp(x2, 6, 0.7)

plot(x2, pdf2, type = "l", lwd = 1, lty = 1, col = "blue")

x <- seq(0, 50, length.out = 100)
y <- dcomp(x, 6, 0.2)

lines(x, y, type = "l", col = "red")
```

[image]